# Glut Solid Shape Renders as Wire when calling GLClear in JOGL

Tags: glut, jogl

I am trying to render some simple solid shapes in JOGL (and Eclipse) and then step through them 'layer' by 'layer'; but when I add the glClear method all I get are wire frames, not the filled shape!? If I comment that line out (as below) displays the solid shape but 'fills' to the largest the shape will be and then does not shrink down again. e.g with a sphere the front half is fine but the back half comes out as a solid cylinder if that makes sense.

```
public void render(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable)
{       
    GL2 gl = gLDrawable.getGL().getGL2();

    **//gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);**

    gl.glColor3b((byte) 0, (byte) 127, (byte) 0);   
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glTranslatef(500, 350, -300);

    glut.glutSolidSphere(300.0, 20, 16);

    gl.glTranslatef(-500, -350, 300);       


    gl.glEnd();     
    gl.glFlush();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Ic an post more of the code if needed.

Thanks
Tim

*EDITED* To make more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert this before you create your sphere... It will tell Opengl to fill the next polygons that are drawn...

```
gl.glPolygonMode(gl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, gl.GL_FILL);
```

if you want the wireframe again, just call:

```
gl.glPolygonMode(gl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, gl.GL_LINE);
```

:)

Comment: Cheers d0lph1n; I had tried that already and it comes up with the same result :(

Comment: After much research I have discovered I am being stupid! Any 3D graphics program just creates the 'illusion' of a solid object by filling in the faces.